# How to include css files in Vue cli 3 with webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

i am new in vue js i am trying to convert my html and css design to vue component

in app.vue file include this way

```
<style>
 @import  './assets/css/style.css';
</style>
```

in webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path")

module.exports = {
    "entry": "./lib/index.js"
,   "output": {
        "path": __dirname + "/build"
    ,   "filename": "xxhash.js"
    ,   "library": "XXH"
    ,   "libraryTarget": "umd"
    },




    module: {

    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [

          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'

        ]
      }
    ]


  }


}
```

this is the error

```
 Failed to compile.

>./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
Module build failed: CssSyntaxError: postcss-import: C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\src\assets\css\style.css:994:1: Unexpected }
    at Input.error (C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:119:22)
    at Parser.unexpectedClose (C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:510:26)
    at Parser.end (C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:353:18)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:68:26)
    at parse (C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:24:16)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:70:24)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:117:12)
    at runPostcss (C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\process-content.js:46:6)
    at processContent (C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\process-content.js:40:10)
    at Promise.resolve.then.content (C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\node_modules\postcss-import\index.js:244:12)
    at <anonymous>
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue 4:14-296 13:3-17:5 14:22-304
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code or errors.  Paste the actual text instead.

Comment: The error says "Unexpected close brace."

Comment: @RobertHarvey i can't figure it out

Comment: An error like "unexpected close brace" can occur if it's expecting something else besides a brace.  Have you fulfilled all of the required elements in `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey i am update my webpack.confg.js

Comment: I'm looking at [this example file](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/), and it doesn't contain single quotes at all.

Comment: You can use either double, or single quotes, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @ParvezAhmed it looks more like the style.css file has some errors with braces in line 994 than the webpack config file itself . build failed due to `CssSyntaxError: postcss-import: C:\Users\Parvez\Desktop\section\src\assets\css\style.css:994:1: Unexpected }`